# Converting an audio file from .oga format to .mp3 using ffmpeg package on nodeJs produces a max of 3 seconds output file no matter the input duration

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am downloading an audio file in `.oga` format and saving it. Then I am trying to convert the file to `.mp3` format, but the issue is the output file is always truncated and a maximum of 3 seconds. I have gone through the fluent-ffmpeg library and I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

I have ffmpeg installed and I'm using the fluent-ffmpeg library. The downloaded .oga file doesn't seem to have any issues, the issue is after it gets converted to .mp3.

I also tried converting to .wav, and I faced the same issue.

Below is my current code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
const axios = require("axios");

const inputPath = __dirname + '/audio/input.oga';
const outputPath = __dirname + '/audio/output.mp3';

const saveVoiceMessage = async (url) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            responseType: 'stream'
        });
        const inStream = fs.createWriteStream(inputPath);
        await response.data.pipe(inStream);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

const convertToMp3 = async () => {
    try {
        const outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
        const inStream = fs.createReadStream(inputPath);
        // I also tried using the inputPath directly, still didn't work
        ffmpeg(inStream)
            .toFormat("mp3")
            .on('error', error => console.log(`Encoding Error: ${error.message}`))
            .on('exit', () => console.log('Audio recorder exited'))
            .on('close', () => console.log('Audio recorder closed'))
            .on('end', () => console.log('Audio Transcoding succeeded !'))
            .pipe(outStream, { end: true })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

const saveAndConvertToMp3 = async (url) => {
    try {
        await saveVoiceMessage(url);
        await convertToMp3();
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```